# Are security options preserved on NTFS disk when upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: security, ntfs

What would happen in the following situation:

In a Windows NT 2003 Server, there is an HDD (D:) with folders on it that are accessible for some users only. These limitations are prepared from the Security tabs of the correspondent folders.

Disk C: is formatted and Windows 10 is installed. Then the same users (with the same usernames) are created. Will these users gain access to the above mentioned folders on D:?

Comment: An administrator can override those security settings, so as long as you have a local admin account on the new system you're fine. But if you use something like [EFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encrypting_File_System) then there will be issues.

Comment: No, encryption is not used.
I will have local Administrator rights. Thank you, @Dan.